# Hydrate property via joining another List<Property> on unique Id

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists, one which is a list of `Equipment` and one which is a list of `WorkflowItems` with an `Equipment` property.  The `Equipment` property within the `List<WorkflowItem>` list only has one of it's values hydrated, `ProcessId`.  The `List<Equipment>` has two properties hydrated, `ProcessId` and `Name`.  I want to hydrate the `List<WorkflowItem>.Equipment.Name` with the value from the single `Equipment` record in the `List<Equipment>`

This LINQ query below will select a generic item out doing basically what I'm looking for, but I would rather just fill in the original list.

```
var list = from item in workflowItems
           join equipment in barcodeEquipmentList on 
                             item.Equipment.ProcessId equals equipment.ProcessId
           select new 
           { 
               ProcessId = item.Equipment.ProcessId, 
               EquipmentName = equipment.Name 
           };
```

**Edit**
The list is going to be relatively small, even doing something like this would be fine (aside from the fact that *this* does not work)

```
workflowItems.ForEach(x => x.Equipment = from e in barcodeEquipmentList
                               where e.Process.Id == x.Equipment.Process.Id
                               select e
                           );
```

**...final edit**

but this does work:

```
workflowItems.ForEach(x => x.Equipment = barcodeEquipmentList
                                           .Where(e => e.Process.Id == x.Equipment.Process.Id)
                                           .FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'hydrated'?

Comment: Maybe that is just lingo used within my team.  I want the Equipment within the WorkflowItem to have it's values populated via the corresponding Equipment item in the List<Equipment> based on ProcessId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the dataset was not very big (less than 20 records), I was able to this as below without a hit to performance

```
workflowItems.ForEach(x => x.Equipment = barcodeEquipmentList
                           .Where(e => e.Process.Id == x.Equipment.Process.Id)
                           .FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code should match your needs:

```
public class Equipment {
    public int ProcessId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class WorkflowItem {
    public Equipment { get; set; }

    public void LoadEquipmentFrom(IEnumerable<Equipment> cache){
        var equipment = cache.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ProcessId == Equipment.ProcessId);
        if(equipment != null)
            Equipment.Name = equipment.Name;
    }
}
```

You could also assign the instance from cache to the existing one, it wouldn't matter since both must have the same Identifier `Equipment = equipment;`. That would be easier if you have more properties to set. To optimize further use an `IDictionary<int, Equipment>` instead of that `IEnumerable<Equipment>`, because you'll be reading that collection very often.

I'm guessing you are implementing a kind of ORM, in this case I can give you a good advice: "There is already something out there that'll fit your needs.".